# Adding items in WPF ListView with columns

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I use this XAML code for the ListView:

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Flag}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ip Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IpAddress}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And this is how I add items to the ListView:

```
ServerListItem item = new ServerListItem
{
    Flag = "IL",
    Name = "Sample Server",
    IpAddress = "sample-server.com"
};
lvServerList.Items.Add(item);
```

Here is the ServerListItem class:

```
public class ServerListItem
{
    public string Flag;
    public string Name;
    public string IpAddress;
}
```

The item is added to the ListView but all columns are empty.
What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WPF does not bind to fields, only to properties. Flag, Name and IpAddress are defined as public fields on your class. Change the class definition to use auto properties instead:

```
public class ServerListItem 
{ 
    public string Flag { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
}
```